# Реализация хлебных крошек (breadcrumbs) в Django MPTT

Tags: django, навигация

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста. На сайте есть каталог товаров, для структуры разделов используется [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt), есть ли какая то стандартная возможность построить хлебные крошки по коду просматриваемого раздела?

Например:

> Женщинам -> обувь -> туфли -> без каблука

Модельки выглядят так:

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField('Раздел', max_length=100)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)
    sort = models.SmallIntegerField('Сортировка', default=100)

class Product(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=100)
    # ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решено!

*** templatetags ***

```
@register.inclusion_tag('catalog/template_tags/breadcrumb.html')
def catalog_breadcrumb(category):
    return {
        'category': category
    }
```

*** breadcrumb.html ***

```
<ul>
    {% for parent in category.get_ancestors %}
        <li><a href="/catalog/{{ parent.slug }}/">{{ parent.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    <li><a href="/catalog/{{ category.slug }}/">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
</ul>
```